# Validity check method not working

Tags: java

alright. So I'm making a sudoku and got a 9x9 grids im comparing two eachother. Array2 is the user's input numbers and Array is the solution. I'm comparing them inside two for-loops to get all the possible x- and y values. It is only returning true.

```
public static boolean validity(int array[][], int array2[][])
{
    for(int j = 0; 9 < j; j++)
        for(int i=0; 9 < i; i++)
            if (array2[j][i] != array[j][i]&& array2[j][i] == 0)
                return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you spot the problem in `int j = 0; 9 < j;` ?

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: What is the validity criterion here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition in both the for loops are wrong, it must be

```
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        for(int i=0; i < 9; i++)
            if (array2[j][i] != array[j][i]&& array2[j][i] == 0)
                return false;
    return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

absolutely it won't return `false` because the condition in both for loops  `9 < j` is always `false` it should be:

```
public static boolean validity(int array[][], int array2[][])
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
        for(int i=0; i < 9; i++){
            if (array2[j][i] != array[j][i]&& array2[j][i] == 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
     }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the second for-loop. It is not executing because `9 > i` is always evaluating to false. Change it from `for(int i=0; 9 < i; i++)`
to `for(int i=0; i < 9; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

It will return true only. Because the condition in the first for loop fails in the first iteration itself.

```
for(int j = 0; 9 < j; j++)
```

Here 9 < 0 . So it skips the loop and returns true.